# How To Populate some filed(column) from table in sails + mongo

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

In Sails I don't need UpdatedAt And createdAt column every time in find, update or in populate method.

In mongoose we can do in This way:

**`db.collection.find({},
{
   UpdatedAt:0,
   createdAt:0
})`**

But in sails, I  don't know how to do that.

Is there any option to do that.

Comment: Can choose fields to include using `Model.find({}, { select: ['id', 'name'] })`. Not sure if exclude is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use This code for selecting specific field :

```
Model.find({field: 'value'}, {select: ['column1', 'column2']})
.exec(function(err, results) {
    if(err) {

    }
    res.json(results);
});
```

But you have to define one criteria for that.